# Center contents of table cell horizontally AND vertically?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to be able to use pure HTML to centre vertically and horizontally the contents of a table cell.

Using the code below, can someone modify it for me. I can see lots of CSS examples, but I'm not a CSS kind of person, and I don't want to really learn anything about it.

It's a one-off edit.

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="7c74ba" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How could I vertically and horizontally centre the `Table Cell` text, without moving the table itself. The table cell sits perfectly where I want it.

Comment: You can use align="center" and valign="middle", but keep in mind these are deprecated and you should use css.

Comment: "I'm not a CSS kind of person". You are so hipster, you rocks \m/

Comment: you already used `style` for background..

Comment: Thank you for everyone's unconstructive criticism of my question. If you don't want to help them politely don't add to this.

I do not require CSS to function in the environment that this is being constructed in, and the question was pretty simple and straight-forward. I do not develop webapps of any kind of a living, and learning a whole structure for a simple task  to edit a single file on the intranet would serve me no purpose. You could see that I am already using CSS structure for the current table, I know enough , without needing to learn everything for a touch here and there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `text-align:center` to your style (hmmm, you're actually already using css rules!!)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/qsvv8/)

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="7c74ba" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if there are more than one column and row then what happen all content placed in centre

Comment: @Danield Thank you! This is exactly what worked for me in this instance. I appreciate your help in this matter.

Answer (score 4):

Well try this:

align="center" AND valign="middle"

but, it's better to use CSS

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using CSS-style in the actual HTML in my example code from above that you can see. I just didn't want to go back to edit one of the `CSS` files this site uses. There are too many of them, and I don't know how they link up.

Comment: If you use in line css, in the style="something" it always will be in front of others css's codes. they top priority. cheers

Answer (score 1):

I know that your question specifies "no CSS," but if you change your mind about that, adding the following CSS to my stylesheet did the trick:

```
td
{
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
```